# sql select * between exact number of rows

Tags: sql, database

I would like to know if I could using select statement retrieve exact position of the rows. e.g rows between 235 & 250. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,
shashi

Comment: Yes, this is possible. I'll tell you exactly how after you accept answers for your former questions.

Comment: What SQL language? Also what is the purpose? if you are doing that because you are showing a subset of results for multi-page viewing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this by multiple way.

1. we can do with the help of offset-fetch clause.

   `select * from Table_Name order by Column_Name offset 234 rows fetch next 16 rows only`

it will fetch the record between 235-250. because it will skip first 234 rows and will fetch next 16 rows.

2. we can use simple select statement with where clause.

   `Select * from Table_Name where Column_Name Between 235 and 250`

it will also fetch same result.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 28):

I don't know of a general way.. but each DB has a way. For example in oracle you can do it with a nested select

**Oracle:**

```
select * from (
select a, b, c from table_foo
where id = 124
)
WHERE rownum >= 235
and ROWNUM <= 250
```

**MSSQL**

```
select * from 
    (select Row_Number() over 
     (order by userID) as RowIndex, * from users) as Sub
    Where Sub.RowIndex >= 235 and Sub.RowIndex <= 250
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 235, 15
```

Comment: Am I going daft, or does >= 235 and <= 250 still mean 16 rows, not 15?

Comment: The below code doesn't work, the while loop doesn't dispaly any values. If I change it to **0** to 150 it works fine. Please help me out here. Anything other than **0** doesn't retrieve any value.

    ResultSet rset1 = stmt.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM iris ) WHERE rownum BETWEEN 10 and 150");
   while(rset1.next())
       {
      System.out.println(rset1.getString(1));
       }

Comment: @bwawok How would you say from 235 and up in MySQL?LIMIT 235, INFINITE?

Comment: @JLaw - You could do:  Limit 235, 999999999999999.  Works fine up to 999999999999999 rows, not so good after that.. but there should be some sane bound.

Answer (score 3):

If your using mySQL you could use the limit command for example:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 235, 15
```

Where the first number is the start index and the second is the number of rows to return.

Comment: Am I going daft, or does >= 235 and <= 250 still mean 16 rows, not 15?

Comment: 16 rows isn't it? as it's inclusive of both boundries

Comment: @MarjanVenema NO its NOT included LIMIT 1,2 will pick 2 records starting to count from index 1. Reminds me of those array indexes that cause havoc by starting to count from zero.

Comment: @Malachi it will return 15 rows. Just tested it now in mysql.

Answer (score 3):

No, that database is set not a sequence, this mean that You the don't have any specific order.

But when specify the order than everything is much simpler.

**Oracle**

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN ) WHERE rownum BETWEEN 235 and 250
```

In this case You have to use rownum

> rownum is a pseudo column. It numbers
>   the records in a result set. The first
>   record that meets the where criteria
>   in a select statement is given
>   rownum=1, and every subsequent record
>   meeting that same criteria increases
>   rownum.

**MS SQL**

```
WITH OrderedRecords AS
(
    SELECT ColumnA, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT * FROM OrderedRecords WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 235 and 250
GO
```

For this You have to specify You own order column

---

For MySQL i don't know how the engine deal with this.

Comment: What do you think an order by clause does?

Comment: Mainly specify the order but You probably refer to how it works; it depend of the db engine, but generally we can say that return and cursor that retrieve the data in specific order, that why in oracle we have to use another select, and in MS SQL we need to specify for our won an row now that oder the set first. This is always "used" last by the database (that why we can use there aliases).

Comment: @bwawok its critical to order especially by id column sorted in alphabetical order for example.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done very easily in SQL Server 2012. By using the new feature of `OFFSET` and `FETCH`. This will help you to pull out desired rows in an already ordered/sorted result set.

**Please see the below example:**

```
SELECT
             PP.FirstName + ' ' + PP.LastName AS 'Name'
            ,PA.City
            ,PA.PostalCode
FROM  Person.Address PA
            INNER JOIN
                        Person.BusinessEntityAddress PBEA
                                    ON PA.AddressID = PBEA.AddressID 
            INNER JOIN
                       Person.Person PP
                                    ON PBEA.BusinessEntityID = PP.BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY PP.FirstName
            OFFSET 0 ROWS
                FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Please notice the `OFFSET 0 and FETCH NEXT 5` written above.
This is will display only 5 rows starting from 0 the row.

Comment: Can we do the same in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server,

```
select * from tablename order by columnname offset 20 rows fetch next 40 rows only
```

It treats 21st row as 1st row and fetches next 40 rows from a 21st row.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft SQL (2005>) you can use the ROW_NUMBER function

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
    SELECT SalesOrderID, OrderDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM OrderedOrders 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 50 AND 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked from me in oracle

```
select * from (select rownum serial,sp.* from sample_table st) sam 
where sam.serial > 10 and sam.serial <= 20;
```