# Sybase shows rows between 100 and 150

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

How to select in Sybase data between rows, e.g.: from row 100 to row 150

`TOP 50` will give me from 0 to 50, but I want from 100 to 150.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635754/sql-select-between-exact-number-of-rows) shows for Oracle and MySQL, but not for sybase.

The `@@rowcount` will specify the count, or am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at SQL Server's `TOP` instead? (Same source code origin.)

Comment: @jarlh sorry I didnt understand , I am using sybase , and top will start from row = 0

Comment: Select top 50 from Inner select top 150, order by something desc

Comment: @Veljko89 like this ? SELECT TOP 2 * FROM EX_EMPLOYEE E 
inner join
(select top 5 * from EX_EMPLOYEE) T
on E.ID = T.ID  order by  E.ID asc , it didnt work for me

Comment: You need ORDER BY in the sub-select as well, opposite directions.

Comment: Ask @Veljko89 instead. Was first.

Comment: @Veljko89 can you post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

It would go something like this ....

```
    select top 50 * from (
        select top 150 * from dbo.YourTable
    ) src order by ID desc
```

You want to select 150 rows order by desc,

So it would go 150, 149 ... 3, 2, 1 ... from that you will select top 50 ... meaning from 150 to 100.

Comment: i got error :An ORDER BY clause is not allowed in a derived table.

Comment: @Moudiz check now, I changed a query a bit

Comment: I want by row not by id , is that possible ?

Comment: Think so, just change order by then ... if you select top 150, and then just desc it ... that should do the trick

Comment: it gave wrong result , it should give 3,4 , it gave 6,7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134074/discussion-between-veljko89-and-moudiz).

Comment: I cannot , because priviliges issue on pc , chating wont load , please lets continue here

Comment: I am not that sure about sybase stuff, they are alike SQL server, but checking other SO answers, can you make something like answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608469/how-to-set-row-number-in-sybase-query ... get those 150 desc into temp table, then select top 50 asc?